# Unclear moments of the proof of Lusin's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

When the author considers the set $F'$ some moments are unclear.

1) Is it true that $A_{\varepsilon/3}$ contains $\bigcup\limits_{n\geq N}E_n$ ? If yes, how to prove it?

2) Why the author takes the condition $\sum \limits_{n\geq N}2^{-n}<\varepsilon/3$? What is the consequence of this inequality?

Would be very grateful if anyone can answer my questions.

Comment: Where is this taken from ?

Comment: @GabrielRomon, Stein, Shakarchi "Real Analysis"

Comment: @GabrielRomon, Do you find iy weird or not? For example, I have spent many hours but did not get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) No, not necessarily, and this is not needed. 2) To get the desired $m(E - F_{\epsilon}) \leq \epsilon$ (see below).

Found the book. Both this proof and the one I know are based on a) Egorov's theorem (Theorem 4.4 there) and b) the fact that for any measurable set $F$ and any $\delta > 0$ there is a *closed* measurable subset $G$ of $F$ such that $m(F - G) < \delta$ (part of Theorem 3.4 there).

In the proof above: $m(E - A_{\epsilon/3}) \leq \epsilon/3$; $A_{\epsilon/3} - F' \subseteq \bigcup_{n \geq N}E_n$ and therefore (here is the answer to your second question!) $m(A_{\epsilon/3} - F') \leq \epsilon/3$; finally, $m(F' - F_{\epsilon}) \leq \epsilon/3$. Together these give $m(E - F_{\epsilon}) \leq \epsilon$.

An alternative way is to prove the theorem for step functions first (in full strength, using just the Theorem 3.4), and, for general case, to use Egorov's theorem (which gives $F \subseteq E$ with $m(E - F) \leq \epsilon/2$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $F$) and the case proven already (which gives closed $F_n \subseteq F$ with $m(F - F_n) \leq \epsilon / 2^{n + 1}$ and $f_n$ continuous on $F_n$; finally we're done with $F_{\epsilon} = \bigcap_{n = 1}^{\infty} F_n$).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer! Your answers as always are very clear! Thank you for help! Also let me ask you one more question relating Lusin's theorem: How to prove rigorously that exists sets $E_n$ such that $m(E_n)<2^{-n}$ and $f_n$ are continuous outside $E_n$? Could you show how to do it?

Comment: See the proof of Theorem 4.3. If $F=\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{m}a_k\chi_{R_k}$ with "almost disjoint rectangles" $R_k$ and $\delta > 0$, then for $Q_k\subset R_k$ chosen so that $m(R_k-Q_k)<\delta/m$, $F$ is continuous on $\displaystyle\bigcup_{k=1}^{m} Q_k$ (now put $F\gets f_n$ and $\delta\gets 2^{-n}$).

Comment: The same argument would work for _simple_ functions (with $R_k\subseteq E$ disjoint measurable, and with $Q_k$ compact measurable - from Theorem 3.4 (iii)).

Comment: (This might be viewed as an apology to what I've stated above - $Q_k$ being closed is insufficient in this case.)